# Owl Carousel v1.3.2 with Vertical slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am using [Owl Carousel v1.3.2](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) in my code base. This is awesome carousel plugin with fully responsive UI. But recently we got one requirement in which we want slider contents should move `vertically upward/downward`. I checked documentation as well as plugin code but haven't found any configuration setting for doing that.

I searched through SO and came across following question [How to use owl carousel vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079495/how-to-use-owl-carousel-vertically) but even that doesn't solve my problem.

Has anybody written any custom code to achieve this functionality? It's not possible for me to add another carousel library just for this vertical slide animation.

Answer (score 3):

This is some sort of a work around. Use `transform: rotate(90deg)` on `.owl-carousel`, or the container class, and rotate 270 deg by `transform: rotate(270deg)` on the items. You have to deal with the margins problems yourself though, but at least the displaying and animation looks fine.