# How do I make this vertical carousel with touch and scroll support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to build a vertical carousel like the one in the image, where I'm able to scroll and use touch.
When the active slide is clicked, the user is redirected else it scrolls to to the element.

Any tips for libraries that can help me achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

[image: visual design of carousel]

Comment: you have to add your html code if you are looking for answers

Comment: this is literally just an unordered list with list items containing links - nothing more to it. I'm looking for a library that can help me make this vertical carousel easier, than having to make it myself.

Comment: Is this a full page slider or a component in a page with other element around it?

Comment: It has an 80px header, then the rest of the page is this element. I'm hoping to do a fullscreen div with background image and then the carousel inside/on top of that.

Comment: You can use Swipe slider jquery for this: https://swiperjs.com/demos/ or https://swiperjs.com/demos/090-vertical.html

Comment: You can use owl carousel refer the below answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079495/how-to-use-owl-carousel-vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making the carousel myself following this tutorial:

[How to build a carousel from scratch in vanilla js](https://medium.com/@marcusmichaels/how-to-build-a-carousel-from-scratch-in-vanilla-js-9a096d3b98c9)

It uses CSS3 animations to move the elements and javascript to swap classes to trigger the animations.